# Excel: Concatenate with Pipe |

Tags: excel, concatenation

Is it possible to concatenate with a Pipe? |

I have an excel with two columns, I'd like them to end up with one cell, with the Pipe dividing the two values.

I.e.

```
Column A       Column B
Apple          Apple Inc.
Orange         Orange Inc.
```

Would hopefully turn into
Column C

```
Apple|Apple Inc.
Orange|Orange Inc.
```

Comment: in cell C1 type `=A1&"|"&B1` and drag it down as far as necessary.

Comment: You could also use `=CONCATENATE(A1,"|",B1)`

Comment: Or since we are listing possible answers, if you have OFFICE 365 Excel then `=TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,A1:B1)`

Answer (score 1):

Just use textjoin()

```
=TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,a1,b1)
```